# Sharepoint 2013 show specific documents from topsite in subsite

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I've created a site collection `url: XXX/sites/kpz/` . I've got three Folders here `C#`, `Java` and `perl` in which I'll add documents.

Now I have three subsites :  `url: XXX/sites/kpz/c#` , `java` or `perl`, on this subsites I want to show just the files from a specific folder on the c# site the C# folder an on the java site the java folder. How can I show the Files from the parentsite and how do I specify the visibility.